maximum possible modulus of the difference in the dimensions of the images of linear operators.
Two linear operators $M,N$ on a vector space $V$ of dimension $10$ on a field $C$ have the same characteristic polynomials. The maximum possible modulus of the difference in the dimensions of the images $M, N$.
As much as I understand it's about similarity matrixes and difference $= 0$.
Sorry english is not my first language.

Help me please with direction to solve problem.

Could you please include your attempts so far?

Can you think of a $2\times 2$ matrix which is not the zero matrix and has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2$? Once you have that down, try to generalize. You should at least get a difference of $9$. Then argue why $10$ is not possible.

Hints: Let $m:=\text{dim}_C(\text{Im}(M)), n:= \text{dim}_C(\text{Im}(N))$. WLOG we can assume $m\leq n$.
$1.)$  Then $m,n\in \{0, 1,\dots, 10\}$. Thus, we get
$$0\leq \vert m-n\vert = n-m \leq 10 -0 =10.$$
$2.)$ If $\vert m-n\vert =10$, then $m=0$ and $n=10$. This would imply that $$\chi_M(0)=(-1)^{10}\det(M)=0\neq \det(N) = \chi_N(0),$$ which contradicts the assumption that $M,N$ have the same characteristic polynomial. Thus, we get
$$ \vert m-n\vert \leq 9. $$
$3.)$ If we could realize $9$, then this would imply that $M$ is the zero matrix. The zero matrix has characteristic polynomial $\chi_M(\lambda)=\lambda^{10}$. As $N$ has the same characteristic polynomial, we need to find a matrix which has rank $9$ and characteristic polynomial $\chi_N(\lambda)=\lambda^{10}$. This means that $N$ has only zero as an eigenvalue. Now pretend for a second that you could bring $N$ into Jordan normal form and find the desired matrix.
